# AWK multiple conditionals not printing

Tags: printing, awk, multiple-conditions

I'm looking for zoom to understand why this:

```
palabra=s_gonzalez
i=10
awk -vvar1=$palabra -vvvar2=$i '( $1 == var1 ) && ( $2 == var2 ) {print $0}' As
```

is not printing anything. The `As` file contains:

```
r_castillo  10
flores  6
s_gonzalez  10
o_gutzwiller    12
h_ji    4
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where're your:

```
vvar2
```

Did you misspell `var2`?

Comment: nope ... awk allow to pass any variable in both forms
    **-vvar1**
or
    **-v var1**

Comment: There are 3 `v`s in `-vvvar1`

Answer (score 0):

As a technique to avoid this sort of problem, you can assign variables without `-v`.  I would rewrite the command:

```
awk '$1==var1 && $2==var2' var1=$palabra var2=$i As
```

It always seems simpler to me to assign variables as arguments after the program rather than as `-v` options before the program.   (`-v` assignments are available in the `BEGIN` block, but that is irrelevant in this case.)